# user/login name on process unknown

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, logins, windows-server

SQL Server version is 11.0.5569.0.

The user/login for the process on a server is as follows:

```
S-1-9-3-412646706-1242810017-220819094-3312857753
```

This is not an orphaned user (as suggested below) because I checked that before entering this post.

I looked at the items running using Ideradm, `sp_blitzfirst`, and `sp_whoisactive`.  The explain plan indicates that this is working with a couple of temp tables that it obviously created in a prior step.

When I ran a script against the 'principals' tables, NADA, nothing.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

`EXECUTE AS USER = 'SomeUser';` where `'SomeUser'` is a user who doesn't have a linked login at the server level will result in SQL Server reporting the login name as a SID starting with `s-1-9-3`.

You can use the `original_login_name` column in `sys.dm_exec_sessions` to determine who or what is impersonating the user without a login; for instance:

```
SELECT SessionID = des.session_id
    , LoginName = des.login_name
    , OriginalLoginName = des.original_login_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions des
WHERE des.is_user_process = 1;
```

I wrote a blog-post over at [SQL Server Science](http://www.sqlserver.science/tools/how-to-identify-a-login-in-sys-dm_exec_sessions-displayed-as-a-sid-starting-with-s-1-9-3/) showing this behavior, and how to identify which database-level-principal is being impersonated.

Answer (score 0):

for the users that do not have a login in the server
follow this link:

--[technet article on orphaned users](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175475.aspx)

**Report on failed users - shows all SQL users on server**

```
USE [<database>]
EXEC sp_change_users_login  'REPORT'

--SQL 2000 and earlier
USE [<database>]
EXEC sp_change_users_login  'Auto_Fix', 'MyUser'

--SQL 2005 onwards
USE [<database>]
ALTER USER [MyUser] WITH LOGIN = [MyUser]

--to find database users (windows accounts) without Server login
select users.name, logins.name
from master..syslogins logins 
    right join sysusers users on logins.sid = users.sid 
where logins.sid is null 
   and issqlrole <> 1 
   and isapprole <> 1   
   and (users.name <> 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA' 
    and users.name not in ('guest', 'dbo', 'sys', 'system_function_schema'))
```

> a number of process running for a long time that are blocking and
>   causing other issues

for this I recommend the procedure called [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com)